# Domain name registration

Tags: url, web, dns

How to register just domain name (**.com)without host. Also is important for me to I have all rights. Can someone tell me the web site for registration just domain or domain with cheap host byt who is legal and who will register domain name on my name? I know some sites who register domain name but how I will be sure that will register domain on my name.

Thank a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That kind of company/website is called a `domain name registrar`.

Use `namecheap.com` and **you** will be the owner of the domain name. Not a host or anyone else. Web hosting is just optional.

**DISCLAIMER:** I do not work for namecheap.com, I just happen to like their services and pricing.